# How to put a background image for a select/dropdown in ie7?

Tags: css, internet-explorer-7, background-image, html-select

Seems `background-image` doesn't work on `<select>` in ie7.
I'm wondering if anybody had luck using any of the filters like AlphaImageLoader or so or any other ideas ?

Please see my [fiddle here](http://fiddle.jshell.net/fQPR4/1/show/).

Comment: Don't understand what is the problem I have the same result in Chrome and IE...

Answer (score 3):

You won't be able to do this. Select boxes have very limited styling capabilities in old IE versions, and this is certainly way beyond their capabilities. I note that it does work in IE8, which is something of a surprise, but I'm pretty certain you'll find it impossible in IE7.

Given that, the only way you'll get anywhere close to this in IE7 is by writing your own selectbox replacement widget in Javascript (or using an existing third party one). Frankly, that seems like overkill for a browser with such low usage these days.

Answer (score 2):

@Spudley is correct.

However, you could do this... which is a huge hack.

Basically, put the `img` in a `div` and position it over the `select` box.  You would also need to add some `&nbsp;` to the `option` elements

**HTML**

```
<select class="example">
    <option>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;dublin</option>
    <option>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;wicklow</option>
    <option>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;kerry</option>
    <option>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;galway</option>
    <option>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;tipperary</option>
    <option>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;cork</option>
</select>

<div></div>
```

**CSS**

```
div{
    background-image: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kkwug.png'); 
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position:1% 45%; 
    height:50px;
    width:25px;
    position:relative;
    top:-35px;
    left:3px;
    z-index:2000;
}

.example{
    background:#F37D7D;
    position:relative;
    width:100px;
}
```

Here is the **demo**: http://fiddle.jshell.net/fQPR4/12/  or  http://fiddle.jshell.net/fQPR4/12/show/

**NB**: You would need to hack the `top` rule in order for it to work and look the same in IE7 and modern browsers.

Answer (score 0):

Do this:

```css
.example {
  
     background: url(http://www.stackoverflow.com/favicon.ico) 96% / 25% no-repeat #fff;

  
}
select::-ms-expand {
    display: none;
}

select{
  
   border: 1px solid #ccc;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
}
```

```html
<select class="example">
  <option>dublin</option>
  <option>wicklow</option>
  <option>kerry</option>
  <option>galway</option>
  <option>tipperary</option>
  <option>cork</option>
 </select>
  
  <select class="example">
  <option>dublin</option>
  <option>wicklow</option>
  <option>kerry</option>
  <option>galway</option>
  <option>tipperary</option>
  <option>cork</option>
 </select>
```